# Integrate $\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{3-\cos^4x}} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{3-\cos^4x}} \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried the substitution $u=tg(\frac{x}{2}) \implies \mathrm{d}x=\frac{2\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^2}$, which gives

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{3-\cos^4x}} \mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{\frac{2u}{1+u^2}}{\sqrt{3-\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}} \cdot\frac{2\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^2}=\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{3-\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}} \mathrm{d}u=$$

then Substitute $t=\sqrt{3-\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}} \implies du=\frac{2\sqrt{3-\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}}{\frac{2u}{ut^2+1}-\frac{2u(u^2-1)}{(u^2+1)^2}}dt$

$$=2\int \frac{1}{t^4-8t^2+16}dt$$

Should I continue or this is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: this leads to an elliptic integral

Comment: What you have written after your substitution doesn't make sense. You need to change $\sin x, \sin 2x$ into functions of $u$.

Answer (score 0):

The good Doctor is correct.  The substitution $u=\cos x$ leads to 
$$
    \int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{3-\cos^4 x}} = - \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{3-u^4}}
$$
However, the antiderivative on the right is not an elementary function.  [Wolfram Alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20-1%2Fsqrt(3-u%5E4))
$$
    -\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{3-u^4}} = -\frac{1}{3^{1/4}} F\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{3^{1/4}}\right) \mid -1 \right)
$$
where $F$ is an elliptic integral of the first kind.